# Customise pactnet contract file name

Tags: c#, .net, pact, pact-net

In my `pactnet` consumer test, I state the contract as follows:

```
PactBuilder.ServiceConsumer("My.Consumer.Application")
    .HasPactWith("My.Provicer.Application");
```

When the contract file is generated it has the following name: `my.consumer.application-my.provicer.application.json`. Is it possible to customise this so it appears as `My.Consumer.Application.My.Provicer.Application.json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge it's not. But why does the name of the contract file matter? It's just an artefact of the testing process that you usually ship to something like the [Pact Broker](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact_broker) or [Pactflow](https://pactflow.io) at which point it will have the original names displayed there.

Usually, you don't even store these files in your git repository.

This being said, you could always rename the file afterwards using any tool of your choosing - Pact doesn't care about the format of the filename when verifying (if you are verifying with a local file).